# Delphi resources for existing .NET developer

Tags: delphi

Can anyone recommend some decent resources for a .NET developer who wishes to get a high level overview of the Delphi Programming Language?

We are about acquire a small business whose main product is developed in Delphi and I am wanting to build up enough knowledge to be able to talk the talk with them.

Books, websites etc all appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Just a trivia -- Anders Hejlsberg, the chief architect of Delphi, is also the lead architect of C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [DelphiBasics](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk) gives a good overview of basic syntax, library functions etc.
- [Essential Delphi](http://www.marcocantu.com/edelphi/default.htm) is a free e-book by Marco Cantu that should give a good overview, also of the VCL

Feel free to ask around here as well, or in the Delphi newsgroups, if you encounter specific issues :)

---

[edit] @Martin:

- There's a [free "Turbo" edition](http://cc.codegear.com/Free.aspx?id=24722) available at the Codegear/Embarcadero website. I guess it has some limitations, so you could also try [downloading the trial version](http://cc.codegear.com/Free.aspx?id=24966).

Answer (score 3):

There's also a [Delphi wiki](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page)
This even has a "Beginning Delphi" page with lots of external links on it. (some of them already mentioned)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.delphifeeds.com/ is a good place to start, it has most news about what is going on in the delphi community.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of videos by Alister Christie at [codegearguru](http://www.codegearguru.com) - check them out :)

edit... @Martin, check out the Turbo products at [CodeGear](http://cc.codegear.com/free/turbo)

Answer (score 0):

@Martin there is a free version.

[Turbo Delphi](http://www.turboexplorer.com/)

If you are comfortable with c# you will see many similarities with Delphi.

I also found the community surrounding the newsgroups to be active and helpful. They have a smilar concept to MVPs they were called Team B (but as Borland doesn't own them the name may have changed now).