# Delphi data structures

Tags: delphi, data-structures, resources

I maybe need to do a project in Delphi and are a beginner in that field. Currently, I am searching the net for ressources and get confused because there are so few resource sites.

First of: can you give me some good websites with resources for Delphi I missed so far?

I was also searching for data structures in Delphi and was wondering if there are cool classes like an ArrayList in Java or something like that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

exist many resources for a  Delphi beginner, see theses questions in StackOverflow

- [Where can I find good beginner-level Delphi tutorials online?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381754/where-can-i-find-good-beginner-level-delphi-tutorials-online)
- [Delphi = Pascal? Resources for Learning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149238/delphi-pascal-resources-for-learning)
- [Learning Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56222/learning-delphi)
- [Delphi resources for existing .NET developer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13086/delphi-resources-for-existing-net-developer)
- [What’s the best Delphi book for a newbie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39647/whats-the-best-delphi-book-for-a-newbie)

A good book about data structures in Delphi is 
***[tomes of delphi: algorithms and data structures](http://www.lulu.com/content/435417)***

[image]
<sub>(source: [boyet.com](http://www.boyet.com/Images/Lulu_Cover.png))</sub>

I think wich the ArrayList Class in Java is very similar to the Generics list ( [TList< T>](http://sjrd.developpez.com/delphi/tutoriel/generics/?page=usage#LII-C) )  introduced in delphi 2009. you can check also the [TList](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=TList) Class in delphi.

Bye.

Comment: +1 for Julian's book (I've just deleted my slightly earlier answer which linked to the same Lulu page).

Comment: Generics in D2009 require a quite of dedication to master all the internal compiler errors, you can come up with

it's better to use D2010 for Generics

Answer (score 4):

I think [DelphiFeeds](http://www.delphifeeds.com/) is a good starting point. There are links to many other Delphi websites including [TorryNet](http://www.torry.net/) where you can find many open source components.

As for structures look at TStrings/TStringList and TList. I use them very often.

For other classes and functions look at [Delphi Basics](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/index.html). There are descriptions and code examples.

Comment: I agree with the DelphiFeeds link. I use it often to keep up to date with what's heppening with the Delphi product.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Project Jedi](http://www.delphi-jedi.org/) and the [JEDI CODE LIBRARY.](http://jcl.delphi-jedi.org/)

> The JEDI Code Library (JCL) consists
>   of a set of thoroughly tested and
>   fully documented utility functions and
>   non-visual classes which can be
>   instantly reused in your Delphi and
>   C++ Builder projects.

Answer (score 2):

Another good resource for components is [delphipages.com](http://www.delphipages.com/).  If you have any questions the best place to get answers is here on stack overflow. :)

For specific cool collections, two units that you will want to open and dig through are contnrs and generics.collections.  Both are in the delphi source directory (..\RAD Studio\x.x\source\Win32\rtl\common) which is installed for licensed versions.

Answer (score 1):

The `TObjectList` is similar to an ArrayList.
I learnt a lot from [delphi.about.com](http://delphi.about.com) and [codegearguru](http://codegearguru.com)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Delphi 2009 or 2010, it comes with several useful data structures where you don't really need to do anything special (TList, TDictionary...).

Answer (score 1):

The Delphi Help is online. I don't know what you have missed but did you see [Getting Started with Rad Studio](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Getting_Started_with_RAD_Studio)?

For data-structures I suggest first to take a look at the [Contnrs.pas unit](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Contnrs) in the VCL. It is located under source\Win32\rtl\common. And if you are lucky and have at least Delphi 2009 then there is also a generics variant in [Generics.Collections.pas](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Generics.Collections)

Answer (score 1):

My favorite Delphi sites is unordered:

- [About Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/)
- [Delphi Basics](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/)
- [Delphi Wiki](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Delphi_Wiki)

And of course this site [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi)

Answer (score 0):

if you're french (or understand french) there is the [Delphi section of Developpez.com](http://delphi.developpez.com/)